# Combining repaint() with Thread.Sleep()

Tags: java, swing, repaint, thread-sleep

What im trying to do is pretty simple, I want to show the steps of an algorithm on the screen, hence why im trying to combine repaint() with sleep(), but I am doing it wrong, Id love it if someone knows enough about it to firstly explain whats wrong with this code, and secondly, what do i do to make it work...

thanks!

in summery, what this code was meant to do is paint 10 red vertices, then balcken em one by one in intervals of 200 milliseconds.

here's the code:

```
public class Tester {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    ShowGUIGraph();
                }
            });
        }

        private static void ShowGUIGraph() {
            JFrame f = new JFrame("something");
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            JPanel p=new JPanel();
            p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            p.add(BorderLayout.CENTER,new SomePanel());
            f.add(p);
            f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
            f.pack();
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
}

public class SomePanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    LinkedList<Vertex> vertices=new LinkedList<Vertex>();
    public SomePanel () {
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            Vertex v=new Vertex(i);
            v.setLocation(20+30*i, 20+30*i);
            vertices.add(v);
        }
        traverseVerticesRecoursive(0);
        traverseVerticesNonRecoursive();
    }
    public void traverseVerticesRecoursive(int i) {
        if (i>=vertices.size()) return;
        vertices.get(i).setColor(Color.black);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        repaint();
        traverseVerticesRecoursive(i+1);
    }
    public void traverseVerticesNonRecoursive() {
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            vertices.get(i).setColor(Color.red);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            repaint();
        }
    }
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (int i=0;i<vertices.size();i++) {
            vertices.get(i).paintVertex(g);
        }

    }
}
   public class Vertex {
        private int x,y,tag,r=20;
        private Color color=Color.red;
        Vertex (int i) {
            tag=i;
        }
        public void setLocation(int x0,int y0) {
            x=x0;
            y=y0;
        }
        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }
        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }

        public void setColor(Color c) {
            color=c;
        }
        public boolean colorIs(Color c) {
            return (color.equals(c));
        }

        public void paintVertex(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillOval(x,y,r,r);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawOval(x,y,r,r);
            g.drawString(""+tag, x+r/2, y+r/2+4);
        }
        public int getR() {
            return r;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Do not sleep in the Event Dispatch Thread; this will cause the GUI to freeze. For animation, use an EDT-friendly utility class, such as [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html).

Comment: @OfekRon, See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: @OfekRon  Many people will not put complete code.  But for the people that will, some good encouragement is to add an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your own code, rather than just code snippets.

Comment: that is an executable code, compiled and tested, and is a simple case of what i had troubles with in my bigger project,so i dont see the problem

Comment: @mre that animation is way more complex then what i was asking for, and yet i didnt get how the simple thing im trying to do is done

Answer (score 1):

Just a few ideas that might make your code cleaner:

1. In your `SomePanel` class, put the traversing code in a method out of the constructor. Constructors are intended for initializing fields.
2. First launch your static GUI, then spawn a worker thread to do the updates via the previous method (this would be your small "engine"). In this thread is were you can call `sleep`.
3. In your `traverseVerticesRecoursive` method, do only the repaint on the UI thread, and the status update on your worker thread.

Tha main modification you should do is not to block the GUI thread with sleep calls, as they have told you in the first answer.

Comment: that is a good answer, but i need a lil bit more info then that, specificly part 3 of your answer needs some more explaining, an exemple would be greatly appriciated, thanks ahead!

Comment: btw, im aware that it is not conventional to put those function calls in the constructer, but that was just for the exemple, didnt want to make it more complex then it is...

Comment: What I was trying to explain is that you usually want to first instantiate an object (and here you'd expect only object creation) and then call a method on that instance, that may launch a process. An example of this is the `Thread` class. First you do `Thread t = new Thread();`, and then you call `t.start();`

Comment: About point #3, your main task, including state updation and sleep time, should be running in a worker thread, simply and plain. Only the GUI refreshing (such as repaints and the first layout made in `ShowGUIGraph`) should run (if needed) in the GUI Thread.

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.sleep` is a long running task. When you a running such a task in the EDT it blocks all repaint requests from being executed. All repaint requests which are pending and which were sent during the sleep phase are queued for future processing.

As a result when the EDT comes out of the `sleep` phase it coalesce all such repaint request (if coalescing is enabled which is the default property) into a single repaint which gets executed. If coalescing is not enabled then all queued request are executed serially without any time gap in between. As a result it seems that the UI did not update.

To correct the situation use a `timer` which triggers periodically after specific intervals of time.

Answer (score 0):

Guy, you could use a new Thread differ with EDT thread to make an animation. For example,

```
 void play() {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            game();
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}

void game() {
    for (; ; ) {
        switch (state) {
            case GameData.ANIMATING:
                // call some function as repaint() to update GUI
                break;
            case GameData.GAME_ENDED:
                return;
            default:
                break;
        }

        diffTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - beforeTime;
        sleepTime = delay - diffTime;
        sleepTime = (sleepTime < 0) ? 0 : sleepTime;
        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
    }
}
```